# coldfusion if - how to look for several items in an IF

Tags: coldfusion

I have an if structure as follows:

```
<cfif #user.personnel_no# is 'xxxxx' or #user.personnel_no# is 'xxxxx' or #user.personnel_no# is 'xxxxx'>
---data
</cfif>
```

how can I do something like:

```
<cfif #user.personnel_no# in ('xxxxx','yyyyy','zzzzz')>
---data
</cfif>
```

to look among all values in if?

or declaring a list and do something like

```
list = 'xxxxx','yyyyy','zzzzz'

<cfif #user.personnel_no# in list>
    ---data
</cfif>
```

Thank you.

Comment: list find, array find,

Comment: can you ellaborate a little more please?

Comment: If you have a list or an array, you can use a coldfusion method to search them for matches. it's the same as testing of x is in list or array y and the result of it can be used in a conditional.

Comment: To get more details, your google search string is `coldfusion list find`.

Comment: Thank you Kevin, that did the trick :) I was abel to make it work, and yes Dan, thank you, I was googling about it :)  thank you both :)

Comment: <CFIF ListFind(list,user.personnel_no)>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<cfscript>
user.personnel_no = 'yyyyy' 

asArray = ['xxxxx','yyyyy','zzzzz']
writeOutput(asArray.find(user.personnel_no)) // 2


asList = 'xxxxx,yyyyy,zzzzz'
writeOutput(asList.listfind(user.personnel_no)) // 2

</cfscript>
```

https://trycf.com/gist/f737ef6d010d4ce37936f1d53d021a62/lucee5?theme=monokai

https://cfdocs.org/listfind

https://cfdocs.org/arrayfind

Comment: Worth noting that there are `NoCase` versions of the functions in case the OP doesn't want to take care of case sensitivity.